# VB.Net: Fomatting of a Listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box that has user inputed values in two out of three column's. What i want to do is Format the listbox so that the second and third column are inline with each other even if the first column is longer in parts then others

e.g

```
1. Zach Newton   100   High Distinction

2.John Smith   100   High Distinction

3.Yon Ho   100   High Distinction

4.Barry Abogorna   100   High Distinction

5.etc   100   High Distinction

6.etc

7.etc

9.etc   100   High Distinction

10.etc   100   High Distinction

11.etc

12.etc

13.etc
```

I basically want to bring numbers 1-9 across one character and make the mark to pad off the longest one

This is my Code for name and mark:

```
         If NumberOfScores < MaxEntries Then
            ScoreArray(NumberOfScores) = Mark

            DataString = (NumberOfScores + 1).ToString + ".  " + _
                NameArray(NumberOfScores).PadRight(15) + _
  Mark.ToString.PadLeft(5)
            LstDisplay.Items.Add(DataString)
            NumberOfScores += 1
        End If
```

Award is controlled by a button but also needs to pad off the longest Mark:

```
     Private Sub BtbGrades_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnGrades.Click

    For I = 0 To lstdisplay.Items.Count - 1
        Dim TempString As String = lstdisplay.Items(I).ToString
        Dim Mark As Double = Double.Parse(TempString.Substring(TempString.Length - 5))
        TempString += " - " + NewAward(Mark)
        lstdisplay.Items.RemoveAt(I)
        lstdisplay.Items.Insert(I, TempString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? As far as I can see, the user is already able to enter the amount of data he wishes. Btw, the two methods look very similar. You might want to extract the repeated code into a method.

Comment: every where therew is 20 i want to have txtLimiter.text this works fine for all but the last section                                               Private MaxEntries As Integer = 20

Comment: Just set `MaxEntries = Integer.Parse(txtLimiter.Text)` somewhere in your code when you are sure that there is a valid value in the textbox.

Comment: Thats not working for me

Comment: A listview or a grid is better suited for this, instead of listbox.

Comment: You're using the wrong control. Use a `ListView` for this; it's exactly what it's designed to do, and has columns to do this alignment. A grid is another option that might be more appropriate.